# RavenDb How to make live projection on MultiMap index?

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have a MultiMap index with two Map functions which indexes comments from two document types:

```
    public class LawDisadvantagesAndLawFixesLastCommentsIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask
    {
        public class IndexResult
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
            public string Author { get; set; }
            public string Text { get; set; }
       }

        public LawDisadvantagesAndFixesLastCommentsIndex()
        {
            AddMap<LawFix>(lawFixes => from lawFix in lawFixes
                                       from comment in lawFix.Comments
                                       select
                                           new
                                               {
                                                   Id = lawFix.Id,
                                                   DateTime = comment.DateTime,
                                                   Author = comment.Author,
                                                   Text = comment.Text
                                               });
            AddMap<LawDisadvantage>(lawDisadvantages => from lawDisadvantage in lawDisadvantages
                                                        from comment in lawDisadvantage.Comments
                                                        select new
                                                                   {
                                                                       Id = lawDisadvantage.Id,
                                                                       DateTime = comment.DateTime,
                                                                       Author = comment.Author,
                                                                       Text = comment.Text
                                                                   });
}
```

What I actually need is not the whole document, but only comment information, so I wanted to apply live projections to this index. But I have no idea how to do it in the case of MultiMap index.

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like this to your index:

```
TransformResults = (database, results) => 
    from doc in results                                
    select new
    {                                          
        DateTime = doc.DateTime,
        Author = doc.Author,
        Text = doc.Text
    };
```

Multi-Map indexes aren't that different from regular Map indexes. They just allow you an easy way to apply the index to 2 (or more) documents.

Comment: Hm... But on which type (LawDisadvantage or LawFix) will doc.Comments property called?

Comment: Both, because you are using a Multi-Map. Both Map statements have to have the same output, so TransformResults can work against that.

Comment: But I did make a mistake in my original answer, which is fixed now.

Comment: Hm... I can't make it work: throws NullRerenceException. I will play with it a bit more